# why foursquare api and web search are different?

Tags: api, location, foursquare

I need to search university buildings by using api.

But one of the building can't search by api, but it shows well on the web.
Can someone let me know why it is different?
Or is there any workaround?
Since foursquare v2 api is no longer supports, I'm using v3 one.

https://foursquare.com/v/sennott-square/4b17fb77f964a520c7ca23e3
this web says this building is "college science building" category.

but below place search api can't find the building as same category.
https://developer.foursquare.com/reference/place-search
query: sennott square
ll: 40.4424081,-79.9550292
radius: 2000
categories: 12036 (this is college science building category number)
sort: distance

the result is empty.

if I query the "sennott suare" with api, it only shows "parking" or "park" category.

Answer (score 0):

The City Guide page and the v3 API are backed by different datasets, the v3 API is backed by our integrated dataset which is a combination of the legacy Foursquare dataset, and the dataset from Factual who we merged with a couple of years ago- but I can confirm that the POI in question, Sennott Square, is included in the integrated dataset and will be returned by the v3 API.

this is what I've got an answer from foursquare. They actually fix few api results that I need.